# Jelastic - Memory consumption is constantly growing when GIT auto-deploy is enabled

Tags: git, memory-leaks, jelastic

I noticed that memory usage is constantly growing when "Check and auto-deploy updates" option is enabled for a GIT deployment.

[image: jelastic memory consumption]

Web service didn't receive any incoming requests during the test. I checked memory consumption through SSH using the following command: `ps aux --sort -rss | head -n15`. Supervisor and node was biggest consumers (30Mb each), but their memory consumption didn't change at the beginning and end of the test. This means my app doesn't consume more memory, but Jelastic reports memory consumption increased.
Memory consumption grows at about 80Mb every 25 minutes with 1 minute check intervals. It seems traffic stops growing and stays stable at around 400Mb.

Is there something I can do to solve the problem?

Jelastic version is 5.7.3

Comment: What is the software stack inside?

Comment: @Ruslan tested with "NodeJS 10.16.3 + supervisor" and "NodeJS 10.16.3 + pm2"

Comment: Ivan, we're are exploring the issue right now, I will update you with our findings right after we find it. Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It is discovered that memory grows in a process systemd-journal that has its own cache, all the events that are being logged in a system are going to RAM first, then they are dropped to a binary journal on a disk, after that used memory is recycled. To decrease the RAM usage in that particular case it may help to change the settings in a configuration file `etc/systemd/journald.conf` to match the following

```
SyncIntervalSec=1m
SystemMaxUse=10M
SystemMaxFileSize=10M
```

then

```
systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

Please request that change from your Hosting Service provide as this file can be changed only under root account. Please let us know if that helped to solve the issue. Have a good day!